# Sampling from a t-distribution in R

Tags: r, random

How can I sample from a t-distribution in R when I want to specify the degrees of freedom (df), the mean and variance?  For example, how would I sample from a t-distribution with 
8 df, mean = 4, and variance = 16?  I imagine I have to use the non-centrality parameter in some sort of way but I am unsure of how.

Comment: Have you looked for anything?  What have you found and why wasn't it right?  FWIW, [my top google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=R+t-distribution&oq=R+t-distribution&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l2j69i64.5272j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I tried googling for it and tried using the rt() function in R for generating random variables but I cannot figure out how to specify the mean and variance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you want the *noncentral* t, or just a scaled and shifted (central) t? To sample from a t distribution with location `m` and scale parameter `s`, do

```
rt(N, df=df)*s + m
```

The variance of a t distribution is `df/(df-2)` so to get a specific variance `v`:

```
rt(N, df=df)*sqrt(v * (df-2)/df) + m
```

Comment: Almost all of the intro to statistics texts I've readuse a shifted Normal distribution to illustrate calculation of "classical" power analyses. The ones that do so are all wrong. To calculate power one should use a proper non-central t-distribution rather than a shifted Normal..

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for `rt`, you see that random variates from the non-central t are returned from:

```
rnorm(n, ncp)/sqrt(rchisq(n, df)/df)
```

So the non-centrality parameter is given to `rnorm` as the mean of the numerator distribution.

Comment: Oh I understand that, I just did not know how to specify ncp correctly.